# Apply the rank function to multiple columns at once

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 35 | 76 |
| 27 | 12 | 43 |
| 29 | 76 | 56 |
| 34 | 54 | 52 |
| 76 | NA | NA |

I want to calculate the ranks (using `rank()` function) for all 3 at once. I'm thinking the `apply()` family would maybe work here? Or would I be better off with a for loop since I'm iterating through the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` or `sapply`

```
df2 <- df1
df2[] <- lapply(df1, rank)
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), rank))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(24L, 27L, 29L, 34L, 76L), b = c(35L, 12L, 
76L, 54L, NA), c = c(76L, 43L, 56L, 52L, NA)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Tidyverse's answer to the `apply` family of functions (`map`). They work similar to the  `apply` family but have a more explicit return value, which is useful. For example:

```r
library(purrr)
map_df(df, rank)
```

This will return a tibble (data.frame), which is what you want.

Of course you could also do the following, if you want a base R solution:

```r
as.data.frame(lapply(df, rank))
```